Como guardar y manejar texto con etiquetas en front y back?
Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que muestra publicaciones como si fuera un foro, mi duda es como guardar y luego manejar textos que tengan etiquetas? por ejemplo como podría guardar:
"Se ha detectado la presencia de <b>ratas</b> en el sótano del edificio.<br/> Se solicita a los residentes tomar las precauciones necesarias y evitar dejar alimentos sin almacenar adecuadamente.<br/> Se avisará a la empresa de <i>control de plagas</i> para su debida atención."

He probado poniéndolo dentro de una etiqueta de párrafo pero no funciona. Además probé guardando a la mala este texto en mi base de datos SQL y lo devolvía diferente:
"Se ha detectado la presencia de <b>ratas</b> en el sótano del edificio.<br/>\r\n    Se solicita a los residentes tomar las precauciones necesarias y evitar dejar alimentos sin almacenar adecuadamente.<br/>\r\n    Se avisará a la empresa de <i>control de plagas</i> para su debida atención."

Estoy trabajando con React en front, mi API es con Node y la base de datos SQL server.
Les agradezco!

estas seguro que las etiquetas son el lugar correcto para tener datos ey enviarlos al backend como lo estas haciendo???
